# How to add margins to a grid cell?

Tags: grid-layouts

I was not able to figure out how can I add some space (margins) surrounding just the "a" and "b" strings of the following grid:

```
Grid[{{"a", "b"},{"c", "d"},{"e", "f"}}, Frame -> All]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
Grid[{{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}}, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {4, 2}]
```

Modification 1

```
Grid[{
  {Framed["a", FrameMargins -> {{1, 1}, {10, 10}}, FrameStyle -> None],
   Framed["b", FrameMargins -> {{1, 1}, {10, 10}}, FrameStyle -> None]},
  {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}}, Frame -> All]
```

Modification 2

```
Grid[{
  {Item["a", ItemSize -> {1, 3}, Alignment -> Center],
   Item["b", ItemSize -> {1, 3}, Alignment -> Center]},
  {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}}, Frame -> All]
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is not the solution i expect, because all rows get affected. I want that just the first row gets the extra margins surrounding its contents.

Comment: Added mod 1.  This could be applied selectively with `MapAt`.